# How to see how much commands per days my redis server executes?

Tags: redis

Currently I have redis installed on VPS, but soon I'd like to move to DBAAS which rates the price according to amount of commands that Redis is processing, i.e. 0.2$ per 100K commands. But before I move to DBAAS I would want to know how much I'm going to need to pay them, but I can't find any stats in redis docs. How and where can I see this value in my current redis? I need statistics of type "per day" and "per month".

Answer (score 0):

You can run the `INFO Stats` command to get the *total_commands_processed* info. It records the total number of commands executed by the server.

In order to get per hour, per day, per month info, you need to run the command per hour, per day, per month, and do the math by yourself.